# MYSQL Dump only certain rows

Tags: sql, mysql

I am trying to do a mysql dump of a few rows in my database. I can then use the dump to upload those few rows into another database. The code I have is working, but it dumps everything. How can I get mysqldump to only dump certain rows of a table?

Here is my code:

```
mysqldump --opt --user=username --password=password lmhprogram myResumes  --where=date_pulled='2011-05-23' > test.sql
```

Answer (score 174, accepted):

Just fix your `--where` option.  It should be a valid SQL WHERE clause, like:

`--where="date_pulled='2011-05-23'"`

You have the column name outside of the quotes.

Comment: For **IN** condition, we can simply use `--where="id IN(1,2,6,10)"`. Where **_id_** is column in table. Ref [--where](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_where)

Comment: Just a note to anyone like me using this to pipe a big datadump to another server that broke in the middle, if you don't specify `--no-create-info` along with your where clause, the new dump will recreate the table and delete the already transferred data! Might be obvious but it's caught me twice now.

Comment: Note that problem wasn't that the column name is outside the quotes. This is a shell command, so you need to write shell syntax for the string `date_pulled='2011-05-23'`. That means you need to quote or escape the single quote characters, so they're included in the string rather than being interpreted as quotes in the shell syntax. Adding double quotes around the whole thing does that, but so would `--where=date_pulled="'2011-05-23'"` (or `--where=date_pulled=\'2011-05-23\'`, or even `--where=date_pulled"'"2011-05-23"'"`).

Answer (score 38):

You need to quote the "where" clause.

Try

```
mysqldump --opt --user=username --password=password lmhprogram myResumes  --where="date_pulled='2011-05-23'" > test.sql
```

Comment: That was exactly what I needed. Another person answered right before you and I selected his answer, but I upvoted you for the help.

Comment: There is another way using query like this: CREATE TABLE new_table
  AS (SELECT * FROM myResumes WHERE where=date_pulled='2011-05-23'); Then you can simply export this table via mysqldump.

Answer (score 2):

Use this code for specific table rows, using LIKE condition.

```
mysqldump -u root -p sel_db_server case_today --where="date_created LIKE '%2018
%'" > few_rows_dump.sql
```