# MySQL- Is it possible to backup mySQL database within a period of time?

Tags: mysql, backup

I am going to backup mySQL database in a period of time. 
For example: Only backup the data from January to June.

Is it possible to do that? The reason I want to do this is I don't want to back up the database that is too old. 
If it is possible please give me some suggestion how to do that.
Thanks.

Comment: Put on hold as off topic, really? I thought SQL queries and even command line tools were appropriate for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you want to backup table ROWS based on date, not tables themselves.

If your tables have a `date` or `timestamp` column, then you can backup certain rows based on date using an `INTO OUTFILE` query, for example.

Or, from the command line, you could use mysqldump with the `--where` option.

See this answer:
[MYSQL Dump only certain rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113213/mysql-dump-only-certain-rows)

Comment: If I need to backup the whole database that included all table in this way, this --where option will still work for this case? The answer provided seems like just backing up certain row of data in a specific table only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
exec("mysqldump --opt -u$db_user -p$db_pass --no-create-info --where date >= '2013-08-01' my_database my_table > backup.sql");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several ways to do it,you can use shell script and run `mysqldump` as cronjob,you should only write something like following script ,then add this to your crobjob.

```
#!/bin/bash
mysqldump --add-drop-table -h <hostname> -u <username> --password=<password> --all-databases > backup.sql
filename="backup.sql."`eval date +%Y%m%d`".tgz"
tar -czf $filename backup.sql 
rm backup.sql
```

then edit crobjob by `crontab -e` and add something like following line:

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/moein/projects/WebService/index.php
#this cronjob executed every min.
```

other way you can use `event` in mysql to get backup.but your mysql version should be > **5.1.8**

better description at [mysql dev page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html).