# Backup SQL DB with query and name according to date

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a query that runs every day, and I want the query to make a .bak and name it according to the backup date.

Can someone lead me in the right direction? - Thanks!

```html
BACKUP DATABASE [MYDB] TO  DISK = N'D:\SQL backups\SERVER1\12345.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'MYDB-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18437910/mysql-is-it-possible-to-backup-mysql-database-within-a-period-of-time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my question by doing some research and I'd like to share it, so here it is:

```html
DECLARE @SQLStatement VARCHAR(2000) 
SET @SQLStatement = N'D:\SQL backups\SERVER1\MYDB-' + CONVERT(nvarchar(30), GETDATE(), 110) +'.bak' 
BACKUP DATABASE [MYDB] TO  DISK = @SQLStatement
```

If you want to use this code, just replace file path to your own folder where you save SQL backups and replace every instance of "MYDB" with your database name. Also, change 'D:\SQL backups\SERVER1\MYDB' with your path. That's all! I hope this script can help many as it has helped me......