# mysql replication without direct connection

Tags: mysql, ssl, replication

I am trying to replicate a remote mysql database to my internal mysql server.

The problem is that I do not have a direct connection available between both mysql servers.

Internally, there is a custom server application (which I've developped my self).  This server application allows incoming connections on 1 port only (with ssl encryption).  Once the connection is made, custom written commands can be executed over that connection (like sending specific backup files, remote browsing, etc... just client/server stuff).

Now I need to add mysql replication, but there is no direct connection possible.  I was thinking to write something like a PORTFORWARD command in my server app which would transfer the replication data to the mysql server interally, something like this:

remote mysql server replication process->remote client application->internal server application-> internal mysql server.

That would probably work, but I think that's gonna be a fragile solution, all connect/disconnect events will need to be forwarded in all circumstances.

Any better ideas for this?

Thanks, 
Vincent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replication in the sense do you want the Remote server database data's  to your Internal server?
if So you could follow [Backup and Restore MySQL Database Using mysqldump](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/backup-and-restore-mysql-database-using-mysqldump/)

Or If want your client server application to access the remote server database follow this [Can't remotely connect through SQL Server Management Studio](https://serverfault.com/questions/128934/cant-remotely-connect-through-sql-server-management-studio)

Comment: mysqldump would be what I need, but I don't want to transfer the entire backup file (it's a big database, > 100 MB each time).  
So an incremental backup would be what I need...  So replication seemed like the way to go I thought.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong: Dude if  new tables are added in your database  often ,then you  would require a mysqldump of your database  often,but if it is  only the data which is changing ,then go for filtering the table  for dump [MYSQL Dump only certain rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113213/mysql-dump-only-certain-rows)

Comment: Thanks Thi49!  I didn't know of a "where" option in mysqldump.  This will be useful!