# Performing grep search on specific rows in a database

Tags: php, sql

I need to perform a grep search on specific rows in a database. I've seen a number of examples on how to perform a grep search using mysqldump but that seems to be for the entire database, I just need to perform it on a certain row. I'm using php code to access and retrieve data from the database at the moment so if there was something similar to grep I could use through php instead that would be even better! Thanks.

*Edit:* Just to expand further on what exactly I need to do. I have a webpage running on a linux server. There's a row called content in my database and each content row contains an xml file which is stored as a blob. I need to search these xml files using grep search or something similar, a grep search [is this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/grep.htm) . From what I understand of grep it needs a pattern so the pattern would be submitted as a text field by the user from the webpage, hope that helps.

Comment: Why not use SQL? What do you mean by "grep search"? Contains search? Use **WHERE foo LIKE '%bar%'** this will find all rows in which column foo contains the value *bar*

Comment: You can dump selected rows only e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113213/mysql-dump-only-certain-rows

Comment: If you really need to use grep and you expect some help, then please give more specifics. Like how do you find those specific rows? Then what do you want to find in them?

Comment: Expanded on the issue there, hope it helps! I think a grep search is more advanced than an sql one, I'm not too sure though I still can't fully get my head around grep, the user uses a grep script at the moment to search through files and requested something similar for my website just not sure what way I should go about it!

Answer (score 0):

As slax0r suggested in the comments, you can use the `LIKE` operator to search rows containing a specific substring:

```
SELECT content FROM my_table WHERE content LIKE '%thesubstringimlookingfor%';
```

You mentionned mysqldump, so I'm assuming you're using MySQL. If you want more than a simple substring, you can use the `REGEXP` operator. For instance, if you want to get all rows for which the 'content' column contains a number:

```
SELECT content FROM my_table WHERE content REGEXP '[0-9]+';
```

Have a look at the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html) to learn how to use `REGEXP` properly.